# GUI and application logic of WindowBuilder interaction java?

Tags: java, jframe, jtextarea, windowbuilder

i have a MainWindow class which has main method,its constructor and initialize() method. The initialize() method has frame, Jbutton and a final Jtextarea. The actionPerformed() is in the another class Data which handles ActionListener. I want to display some text after the button is pressed in the Jtextfield which is inside only private variable frame of the MainWindow class.I haven't mentioned the Application logic, help me interact with it and GUI.. thank you !!!!!

The MainWindow class:

```
    public class MainWindow {
    private JFrame frame;
    public Data data;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
             public void run() {
                 try {
                    MainWindow window = new MainWindow();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                 }
             }
         });
    }

    public MainWindow() {
         this.data = new Data();
         initialize();
     }

     private void initialize(){

         frame = new JFrame();
         frame.setBounds(100, 100, 396, 469);
         frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
         frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

         final JTextArea textarea = new JTextArea();
         textarea.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.PLAIN, 75));
         textarea.setTabSize(15);
         textarea.setBounds(12, 28, 370, 85);
         frame.getContentPane().add(textarea);

        JButton button7 = new JButton("7");
        button7.addActionListener(this.data);  // Data data class has the actionperformed() method
        button7.setActionCommand("7");
        button7.setBounds(12, 125, 65, 73);
        frame.getContentPane().add(button7);
        }
}
```

Then the class Data is:

```
    public class Data implements ActionListener {

    public String s;

    public Data(){
        //constructor
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
             // this will set string s with some string 
            // that has to be returned to be displayed
            // in the Jtextarea of the frame in MainWindow
  }

    public string returnString(){
             return s;
    }
```

i just want to set the JtextArea of the frame variable in MainWindow class..please help

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can simply pass the reference of the TextArea to your ActionListener via getter or constructor. Here I just used getter

```
public class Data implements ActionListener {
public JTextArea textArea;

public Data() {
    //constructor
}

// here I used setter
public void setTextArea( JTextArea textArea ) {
    this.textArea = textArea;
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // this will work, if you click the button 7
    textArea.setText("Any modification you want");
}
}
```

And add this code in your initialize() method after textarea initialization

this.data.setTextArea(textarea);

Hope it helps.

**UPDATE**

```
public class MainWindow {
private JFrame frame;
public Data data;

final JTextArea textarea;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                MainWindow window = new MainWindow();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

public class Data implements ActionListener {

public String s;
public MainWindow mainWindow;

public Data( MainWindow mainWindow ) {
    this.mainWindow = mainWindow;
    //constructor
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    s = "test";
    // this will set string s with some string
    // that has to be returned to be displayed
    // in the Jtextarea of the frame in MainWindow
    mainWindow.updateTextArea(s);
}

public String returnString() {
    return s;
}
}
```

That is just a simple implementation.

Comment: I am able to set String s in my Data class but the actual problem is to RETURN THAT STRING AND SET IT in the JTextArea textarea in MainWindow class. PLEASE HELP ME TO RETURN THAT JTextArea and add to JFrame frame in MainWindow class... thank you !!!

Comment: Let's think. Logically, the ActionListener will catch your action and run a code inside actionPerformed, therefore if you want to handle code inside MainWindow, thus you must **create a method inside MainWindow and call it from ActionListener**.